# how to make local orientation after transforms were applied?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've got Blender 2.92.
So i have that mesh that I have transformed a bit (a rectangle tilted on X axis, scaled up and down in few places so it looks like a stool leg), the I have applied all transforms and I've lost normal transform orientation.
I've watched few videoes on creating a custom one but that doesn't do anything - as soon as switch back to that mesh, it's a standard original orientation (global one). I already tried creating that custom orientation in object and edit mode - it's called "test" in the screenshot attached - and it always switches back to global settings, no matter which orientation i choose.
Reading Blender manual never helps - they give the basics, and it's covered in the youtube videos anyway - so thank you in advance for telling me to read it, I've already done that.
What am I missing that people in videos have no problems doing that, and I have? I'd like to extrude or even move the top or bottom face of this mesh at the same angle as the sides are.
[image: blender mesh orientation]

EDIT: I have found out that going to the Viewport Gizmo menu, and changing the orientation in that menu works.
How to unblock it or make the other menu work? Not a big issue now that it's solved, but it would save me hours on searching for that.

Comment: Why did you apply all transforms?  What problem was that intended to solve?  Because the short answer is, if you don't want to lose your local axes, then don't apply all transforms (importantly, don't apply rotation.)

Comment: I have applied transforms because it solves other issues when scaling, extruding and so on - so I have automatically done that. But I have found something... I'll add that comment to the main post in a minute.

Comment: the problems you're describing are solved by applying scale.  So only apply scale, not all transforms.

Comment: ok thanks. i'll try not to mess it up next time...

Comment: In addition to mentioned in the comments, if you use gizmo, choose transform orientation in gizmo dropdown (left corner). Dropdown in the center changes for the operators run with shortcuts (yes, not the best design choice out there).

Comment: Well... it's for free. I can't complain on design. Is it actually right top corner? Or is there a 3rd Gizmo menu? I can only wish it was easier to find all information about that :)

Comment: I'm referring to transform orientation dropdown, not menu to enable gizmos to be displayed. See related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167900/what-is-the-shortcut-for-orientation